# put the Element on certain points on the background in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have an image, I want to put a `TextView` on a certain point(**on the brown rectangle**) in different devices with **different screen sizes**. My image is below:
**CAUTION**:the scaleType of the `ImageView` is **CenterCrop**
[image: my background]

in image below I show where I want to put the TextView:

[image: textview bg]

And this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/startpage"<!-- my background-->
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found it myself, see these java codes:
I find the display width and height, then calculate the scale, the according to the scale I scale the margins.

```
@Bind(R.id.name_tv)TextView nameTV;

public final static float bgWidth = 768;
public final static float bgHeight = 1136;

public float tVsRightMargin = 123;
public float nameTVtopMargin = 314;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ResourceManager.setActivity(this);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
ButterKnife.bind(this);

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
Log.v("MainActivity","displayWidth: "+displayWidth);
Log.v("MainActivity", "displayHeight: " + displayHeight);

float scale = Math.max(displayWidth/bgWidth, displayHeight/bgHeight);
Log.v("MainActivity", "scale: "+scale);

float bgScaledWidth = scale*bgWidth;
float bgScaledHeight = scale*bgHeight;

tVsRightMargin *= scale;
nameTVtopMargin *= scale;

if(bgScaledWidth>displayWidth) {
    tVsRightMargin -= ((bgScaledWidth - displayWidth) / 2f);
}
if(bgScaledHeight>displayHeight){
    nameTVtopMargin -= ((bgScaledHeight-displayHeight)/2f);
}

nameTV.setText("محمد");
nameTV.setTypeface(ResourceManager.getTypeface());


Log.v("MainActivity", "top margin: " + nameTVtopMargin);
Log.v("MainActivity", "right margin: " + tVsRightMargin);
((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) nameTV.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, (int) nameTVtopMargin, (int) tVsRightMargin, 0);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of options how to do that, but seeing your pics I'd simply make my `TextView` aligned to top-left corner and set its layout margin to right values in `dp` (which I'd simply figure out in any graphics program).

Comment: BUT Is this way work on different screen size? I don't think. How can I found the leftMargin dynamically according to the fact that image is scaled and the scale factor is different on different screen sizes. This is my challenging problem. How Can I find the LeftMargin?

Comment: By `the fact that image is scaled` you mean `scaled` or `stretched`? if `scaled` then you shall not care much as that's why I said you shall use `dp` for you position adjustment. If `stretched` then I'd say you got this done wrong as it simply will look ugly

Comment: do what I asked, then try it on different screen size to know what I mean. `dp` doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. I am quite new so someone with more knowledge would most likely have a better answer. But, you can try to align with Relative Layout. Or you can use a layout gravity to change it so that it "gravitates" towards where you want it to be.

Comment: I want to put the textView on the brown recatangle, and I want to do this in different screen sizes. It's not simple.

Comment: I can't comment on the answer Marcin gave as I don't have enough reputation points to comment. However, it seems as if he is saying you should play around with the different margins until it works.

Comment: android:layout_marginLeft

Comment: Like its current one? You set it. So basically just do android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" then 20dp then whatever until it looks good. Also there is android:layout_marginTop as well that should help with top margin

Comment: it's not a good idea, I want to do it dynamically and programitacally, It's not a good idea to examine all screen sizes

Comment: this solution is not good, because I should examine all screen sizes, I like to write a code and do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start with also [draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) which is a tool that helps u to select where do u want the content to fit inside the picture.

> The Draw 9-patch tool is a WYSIWYG editor that allows you to create
>   bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of
>   the view and the size of the screen.

After that you will need to check alignment and such stuff. like top left, padding-top... etc